# NodeJS Read File Name is Japanese Characters

Tags: node.js

I have a file name is momo1.json. I can read them in Nodejs

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonWelcome = fs.readFileSync(WELCOME_JSON, UTF8_FORMAT);
var dataWelcome = JSON.parse(jsonWelcome);
```

But now i change file name is ももたろう.json. I cant read file anymore, tell my why and solutions i can read file name by japanese charaters

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **require()** instead:

```
var dataWelcome = require("./ももたろう.json");

//output the data to see if it works
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataWelcome));
```

---

<kbd>**[Live Demo](https://repl.it/@NLDev/nodejshiragana)**</kbd>

Comment: @NguyễnKiên I tested it and it does work for me (even included a demo in my answer). Do you get any error? Where do you set the `WELCOME_JSON` variable? Please add the full code snippet to your question.